# C++ type conversion from a variable to a reference

Tags: c++

When doing a type conversion from a variable to a reference, like:

```
float f = 1.0f;
int a = (int&) f;
std::cout << a;
```

Why do I get the actual bit-representation of the float value (and not the numeric value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is ***undefined behavior***, technically speaking. Your C-style cast does a `reinterpret_cast` which isn't defined for convering a `float` lvalue to `int&`. Maybe you just wanted to cast to an `int`?

Answer (score 1):

Because reference in C++ means "another name for". So when you cast something to a reference you just give it another name, and not perform a value conversion from floats to integers.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you converting a variable to a reference and then storing it in a variable?